# Attempting to change a dash to a letter with loop

Tags: java, string, loops, replace, char

So I'm writing a program for this brand new, never heard of game called hangman (ha.) and I'm having a really hard time writing a loop that will give me the results I want.  I'm stuck at the point where a correct letter has been guessed (via button press) and revealing the correct letters in the line of dashes that represent the hidden word. Now when I run this loop, my tester popup still pops up "Match!---" or however many dashes the current secret word has.  It's literally as if the replaceAll doesn't actually replace it!  I've been stumped on this for hours now with no break so it would not surprise me if it is something extremely obvious I am missing.

```
JButton btnA = new JButton("A\n");
btnA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String letter = "a";
        char ch = 'a';
        if (go.getWordInQuestion().contains(letter)) {
            for(int i = 0; i<go.getWordInQuestion().length(); i++) {
                //Replace dashes with correctly guessed letter              
                if(go.getWordInQuestion().charAt(i)== 0)
                    go.getGuessLength().replaceAll("[^" + letter + "]", "_").charAt(i);
            }
            //check to see what the new value of the "hidden word" getGuessLength looks like                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Match! " + go.getGuessLength());
            txtGuess.setText("" + go.getGuessLength()); 
        } else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Match :(");
    }
});
```

*****EDIT*******
Ok so I've made progress (I think).  I have now written a loop that changes the dashes to letters!! The only problem? it changes all of them. -___- So now when I press button A, if theres a match, instead of ---, it will read aaa.  I definitely realize this issue is probably extremely elementary but when it comes to java, I'm a slow learner! I appreciate all the positive and informative feedback!

```
JButton btnA = new JButton("A\n");
btnA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String letter = "a";
        StringBuilder guessA = new StringBuilder('a');
        for(int i = 0; i<go.getGuessLength().length();i++) {
            if(go.getWordInQuestion().charAt(i)=='a') {
                String partialWord = go.getGuessLength().replace("-", letter);
                txtGuess.setText(partialWord);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Match! " + partialWord);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

*****EDIT TWO******

Alright! I think I have finally resolved the issue thanks to your guys help! When a user presses the 'A' button, and if there is an A in the hidden word, it is now successfully replaced with a dash! woohoo!

```
btnA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String letter = "a";
        StringBuilder guessA = new StringBuilder(go.getGuessLength());
        if(go.getWordInQuestion().contains(letter)) {
            for(int i = 0; i<go.getGuessLength().length();i++) {
                if(go.getWordInQuestion().charAt(i)=='a') {
                    StringBuilder partialWord = guessA.replace(i,i+1, letter);
                    txtGuess.setText(guessA.toString());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Match! " + partialWord);
                }
            }
        } else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect");
    }
});
```

Comment: In addition to JB's note, the logic is pretty hard to follow.  What is this statement supposed to test: `if(go.getWordInQuestion().charAt(i)== 0)`?  It's pretty unusual to test a character for zero.

Comment: And I sure hope you don't intend to repeat the above code for the letters B-Z.  Even if you have 26 different button handler routines (which I'm sure can be avoided), the rest of the code can be a common subroutine.

Comment: Ok, I think I've confused myself; I thought char 0 was defined to be the letter a?  So I wrote the above line to test if my secret word is equal to the letter a at the point charAt(i), the guessLength is also equal to a.  So my loop is supposed to change the every guessLength.charAt(i) from a "-" to the letter a.

Comment: Zero is the numeric value of the ASCII control character NUL.  Not something you'd use in ordinary circumstances (except in C to indicate the end of a string).  "a" is decimal 97 or hex 61.  See an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Hint: To fix your current problem, instead of using `String.replace`, make your getGuessLength object be a StringBuilder and use `StringBuilder.replace(i,i,letter);`

Comment: So change the line StringBuilder guessA  to     StringBuilder(go.getGuessLength()); ? And then the String partialWord to equal guessA.replace(i,i,letter) ??

Comment: Ok Ok Ok. I figured it out and it worked! ...well partially.  It doesn't really replace the - with an "a", it more so just inserts one in the middle.. how do I correct that? Why is it not simply replacing the dash?

Comment: If you use replace it will replace.  Sounds like you're using insert.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code doesn't do anything:

```
go.getGuessLength().replaceAll("[^" + letter + "]", "_").charAt(i);
```

`replaceAll()` doesn't modify the String (Strings are immutable in Java). It returns a *new* String where the characters have been replaced. You're calling `charAt(i)` on this new String, and don't do anything with this char.

Comment: Ok so I've made progress (I think).  I have now written a loop that changes the dashes to letters!! The only problem? it changes all of them. -___- So now when I press button A, if theres a match, instead of ---, it will read aaa.

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll()` uses a regex as its target for replacement. You probably just want `replace()`, which still replaces all matches but uses plain characters for its target.

That said, the simplest solution is just one line of code that uses `replaceAll()` and turns the guessed letters into a regex that matches all *other* letters.

Given:

```
String word = "foo"; // the word people are trying to guess
String guesses = "one"; // the characters guessed so far
```

Here's the one line that will produce the required output:

```
String display = word.replaceAll("[^" + guesses + "]", "-");
```

When executed with the above values, `display` will be `-oo`.

Comment: Much, much simpler to avoid REs and use StringBuilder.replace.

Comment: @HotLicks I disagree completely: This one line expresses in code the one-line intention "replace every letter not yet guessed by a dash". No loops, no extra lines and logic where bugs can lurk.

Comment: @HotLicks depends on your experience - I can read it just fine, a beginner not so much. However, how comprehensible is a multi-line chunk of code taken as one "operation"? I reckon it would take the average java programmer about the sand amount of time to comprehend both.